# Read irregular format text file mixed of text with/without space and numbers

Tags: r, time-series, zoo, na, read.table

Sample data look like this (fyi I have hundreds of files like this). The tricky part is the "NO RECORD" in the file. I haven't been trying hours to get it into R without any success

```
BEGIN DATA
RIM
DATE           AF         QD         QU 
09/30/1920      NO RECORD       370.00  NO RECORD   
10/01/1920      NO RECORD       391.00     391.00 
10/02/1920      NO RECORD       496.00    MISSING 
10/03/1920      NO RECORD       660.00    MISSING 
10/04/1920      NO RECORD       881.00    MISSING 
10/05/1920      NO RECORD       660.00    MISSING 
10/06/1920      NO RECORD       515.00    -9999 
10/07/1920      NO RECORD       443.00    NO RECORD 
10/08/1920      NO RECORD       443.00    MISSING 
10/09/1920      NO RECORD       443.00    443.00 
10/10/1920      NO RECORD       443.00    MISSING
```

**This is my latest R code**

```
library(zoo)

# function to read data
obsRead <- function(path2file, filename, number_line_skip, header_or_not) {
  tmpName <- paste(path2file, filename, sep="")
  tmpData <- read.zoo(tmpName,
                   tz='', stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE,
                   header=header_or_not, skip=number_line_skip, 
                   na.strings = c("NA", "N/A", "MISSING", "NO RECORD", "-9999"), # tell zoo what NA values look like
  qName <- c("AF", "QD", "QU")
  names(tmpData) <- qName
  index(tmpData) <- as.Date(index(tmpData)) # Convert index from POSIXct to Date
  str(tmpData)
  return(tmpData)  
}

dataDir = "path/to/file/"
dataFile <- "sampleData.txt"
nLineSkip <- 3
header_or_not <- FALSE

Q_obs <- obsRead(dataDir, dataFile, nLineSkip, header_or_not)
```

**And the error I got from R**

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 2 did not have 6 elements
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: So is the data fixed width (the headers seems a bit off here)? Or maybe tab delimited?

Comment: Random? Are you sure? Who would create such a format? Have you actually looked at the bytes of the file? You'd be better off replacing all the "NO RECORD" values with "NORECORD" before you tried to read the data. If you're on unix you could pipe it through `sed`. Or you could use `readLines()` in R, do the transformation, then send to `read.table`. But i can't believe the data file doesn't have any logic at all to it.

Comment: Oh my bad. Sorry for misunderstood your question. I've just checked: column 1 has the width of 11, col. 2 has 15, col. 3 has 13 & col.4 has 11. Thanks also for the suggestion!

Comment: `read.fwf` can help read fixed-width files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided `NO RECORD` is consistent, this should give you a start:

```
tmp <- readLines("sample.dat")

# substitute 'NO RECORD' for 'NORECORD' and use read.table()
# to process the collapsed vector

tmp.collapse <- paste(gsub("NO RECORD", "NORECORD", 
                      tmp[4:length(tmp)]), sep="", collapse="\n")

# get the column names from the third row and use them in the data table

read.table(textConnection(tmp.collapse), 
           header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, 
           col.names=unlist(strsplit(tmp[3], "\ +")))

##          DATE       AF  QD       QU
## 1  09/30/1920 NORECORD 370 NORECORD
## 2  10/01/1920 NORECORD 391   391.00
## 3  10/02/1920 NORECORD 496  MISSING
## 4  10/03/1920 NORECORD 660  MISSING
## 5  10/04/1920 NORECORD 881  MISSING
## 6  10/05/1920 NORECORD 660  MISSING
## 7  10/06/1920 NORECORD 515    -9999
## 8  10/07/1920 NORECORD 443 NORECORD
## 9  10/08/1920 NORECORD 443  MISSING
## 10 10/09/1920 NORECORD 443   443.00
## 11 10/10/1920 NORECORD 443  MISSING
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
library(zoo)
L <- readLines("path/to/file/sampleData.txt")
L <- gsub("NO RECORD", "NO_RECORD", L)
z <- read.zoo(text = L, header = TRUE, skip = 2, format = "%m/%d/%Y",
        na.strings = c("NA", "N/A", "MISSING", "NO_RECORD", "-9999"))
z
```

giving:

```
> z
           AF  QD  QU
1920-09-30 NA 370  NA
1920-10-01 NA 391 391
1920-10-02 NA 496  NA
1920-10-03 NA 660  NA
1920-10-04 NA 881  NA
1920-10-05 NA 660  NA
1920-10-06 NA 515  NA
1920-10-07 NA 443  NA
1920-10-08 NA 443  NA
1920-10-09 NA 443 443
1920-10-10 NA 443  NA
```

Comment: Thanks @G. Grothendieck for a very clean solution!

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on @MrFlick 's comment suggesting `sed`, `fread` accepts system commands directly:

```
fread("sed 's/NO RECORD/NORECORD/' < yourFile.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt Dowle! This is what I got why I tried your suggestion. Note that I'm using GNU sed for Windows (http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/)

    > fread("sed 's/NO RECORD/NORECORD/' < sample_data.txt")
    > Error in fread("sed 's/NO RECORD/NORECORD/' < sample_data.txt") :
    > Not positioned correctly after testing format of header row. ch=' '
    > In addition: Warning message:
    > In fread("sed 's/NO RECORD/NORECORD/' < sample_data.txt") :
    > Starting data input on line 3 and discarded previous non-empty line: 09/30/1920 NORECORD 370.00 NO RECORD

Comment: @thecatalyst That feels like a separate problem. From the error message it looks like v1.9.5 but please always state. Will need to see the data then, preferably as file on dropbox or similar. Please raise as an issue rather than comments. You can put a link to the issue into a comment.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I updated it here https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/964